# Can't change the size of particles in particle physics settings

Tags: particles, physics

I was trying to increase size of particles in a particle system by adjusting the size property in physics settings as seen in the tutorial I was watching.But that setting is not available to me.Could any one tell where I went wrong ? and how to solve it ? Thanks in advance ( Blender v2.79 )

[image: My Particle system settings]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Size is only for particle physic.

The tip value should in most cases be at zero and can cause a weird look if it is to high.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do it in the physics settings.But the size property is not shown in my window.

Comment: You are in hair so if you can find size it will not do anything